# Using t-sql to select aggregate when date difference is not just equal but small

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

I have a table where I want to select the maximum of a column but based on when the date difference is equal **or** small (lets say 3 days).  When two subsequent dates are very close, the data are likely spurious and I want to get the highest `state` when that happens.

My data looks similar to this

```
DECLARE @TestingResults TABLE (
IDNumber varchar(100),
DateSeen date,
[state] int)

INSERT INTO @TestingResults VALUES
('A','2015-04-21',2),
('A','2015-05-08',2),
('A','2015-07-01',3),
('B','2014-06-18',100),  -- this is the one I want
('B','2014-06-19',2),
('B','2014-07-31',2),
('B','2014-08-11',3),
('B','2014-09-24',3),
('B','2014-10-24',3),
('B','2014-11-24',3),
('B','2014-12-15',3),
('B','2015-01-12',3),
('B','2015-01-13',400),  -- this is the one I want
('B','2015-04-06',10),   -- either will do
('B','2015-04-07',10),
('B','2015-07-06',3),    -- either will do
('B','2015-07-07',3),
('B','2015-10-12',3),
('C','2012-02-20',3),
('C','2012-03-12',3),
('C','2012-04-02',3),
('C','2012-11-21',3)
```

What I really want is something like this where I take the maximum of `state` when the difference between dates is < 3 (note, some of the data may have the same `state` even when the differences in date are small ...) :

```
IDNumber DateSeen   state
A   2015-04-21  2
A   2015-05-08  2
A   2015-07-01  3
                   -- if there are observations < 3 days apart, take MAX
B   2014-06-18  100
B   2014-07-31  2
B   2014-08-11  3
B   2014-09-24  3
B   2014-10-24  3
B   2014-11-24  3
B   2014-12-15  3
                  -- if there are observations < 3 days apart, take MAX
B   2015-01-13  400
                  -- if there are observations < 3 days apart, take MAX
B   2015-04-07  10
                  -- if there are observations < 3 days apart, take MAX
B   2015-07-07  3
B   2015-10-12  3
C   2012-02-20  3
C   2012-03-12  3
C   2012-04-02  3
C   2012-11-21  3
```

I guess I could create another variable table to hold it and then query it but there are a couple of problems.  First as you can see, `IDNumber`='B' has a couple of triggers in its sequences of dates so I am thinking there should be an 'smarter' way.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. What is your ideal result set from the data you've shown?

Comment: I edited the question for clarity and added a result set.  I think I need to do a window function based on the dates...

Comment: What do you do if, say, you had a string of five dates, each two days apart (such as Dec 1, 3, 5, 7, 9)? Dec 1 is within three days of Dec 3, but Dec 3 is within three days of Dec 5, and Dec 5 is within three days of Dec 7, and so forth. How would you resolve this--as one big set, or something else?

Comment: Great question!  My data is actually about patients and their results so, scientifically I am not really what I would do.  For the purposes of this question I think it is probably most realistic to have that a user controlled value (lets say 4 days).  To make it work properly you'd have to have the minimum date as the date to start with and then only lump together results within the forward/backward 7 days...  So in you sequence, Dec 1,3, and 5 is one chunk.  Then Dec 7 and 9 is the next chunk.

Answer (score 0):

After your clarifying comments (thanks for that!), I would do this as follows:

```
SELECT  ISNULL(high.IDNumber, results.IDNumber) AS IDNumber,
        ISNULL(high.DateSeen, results.DateSeen) AS DateSeen,
        ISNULL(high.[state], results.[state]) AS [state]
FROM @TestingResults results
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 IDNumber, DateSeen, [state]
    FROM @TestingResults highest
    WHERE highest.DateSeen < results.DateSeen
    AND highest.IDNumber = results.IDNumber
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY,highest.DateSeen,results.DateSeen) <=3
    ORDER BY [state] DESC, [DateSeen] DESC
) high
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM @TestingResults nearFuture
    WHERE nearFuture.DateSeen > results.DateSeen
    AND nearFuture.IDNumber = results.IDNumber
    AND DATEDIFF(DAY,results.DateSeen,nearFuture.DateSeen) <=3
)
```

This is almost certainly not the most elegant way to achieve this (I suspect this could be done more efficiently with Window Functions or a recursive CTE or similar), I believe it gives you the behaviour and results you desire.

Comment: That is somewhat close but I really need the MAX or MIN if there is something within 3 days (not just the newer value).

Comment: I added a better use case to show this (with a value of 100)

Comment: If you add this as a condition to the subquery it will work as desired `AND nearFuture.state >= results.state`

Comment: Are you sure? Adding that statement to the `WHERE` clause will return the record for 2014-06-19 (state = 2) as well as the record for 2014-06-18 (state = 100 in new example). I'm just working on a solution that gives you what you want though now that I understand you want the max for each 3 day period - I'll edit my answer later on if someone doesn't beat me to it.

Comment: Ok, updated solution edited into answer - hopefully that will do the trick for you, let me know how you get on.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it using a recursive CTE:

```
WITH TestingResults AS (
    SELECT 
        *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IDNumber, DateSeen) AS RowNum
    FROM @TestingResults
), Data AS (
    SELECT
        tmp1.IDNumber,
        tmp1.DateSeen,
        tmp1.state,
        tmp1.RowNum,
        tmp1.RowNum AS GroupID
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            *
            ,ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, DateSeen, LAG(DateSeen, 1, NULL) OVER(PARTITION BY IDNumber ORDER BY DateSeen))) AS AbsPrev
        FROM TestingResults
    ) AS tmp1
    WHERE tmp1.AbsPrev IS NULL OR tmp1.AbsPrev >= 3 --the first date in a sequence

        UNION ALL 

    SELECT 
        r.IDNumber,
        r.DateSeen,
        r.state,
        r.RowNum,
        d.GroupID
    FROM Data d
        INNER JOIN TestingResults r ON 
            r.IDNumber = d.IDNumber 
            AND DATEDIFF(DAY, d.DateSeen, r.DateSeen) < 3 
            AND d.RowNum+1 = r.RowNum
)
SELECT MIN(d.IDNumber) AS IDNumber, MAX(d.DateSeen) AS DateSeen, MAX(d.state) AS state
FROM Data d
GROUP BY d.GroupID
```